# Фаервол виндовс сервер

Tags: администрирование

Возник вопрос недавно. На сервере 2 внешних ip адреса на 1 сетевушке. я бы хотел настроить фаервол для каждого ip отдельно. подскажите пжл. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

[Стильно Модно Молодежно](http://www.kerio.ru/ru/control)

Comment: и ведь не поспоришь...